# Good Database Design Tools?

Tags: database

Does anyone know of a good web-based GUI I could use for database design? It is going painfully slow in Photoshop.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server both have excellent DB design tools.  Need it be web-based?  Native apps are much easier to use.

Comment: You should try the tools @Mikecito mentioned, you can even create your database and then create the diagram... or the other way, first the diagram, then the database. Your choice!

Comment: Photoshop for DB Design!!! you gotta be joking

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I've seen Powerpoint being used for that......

Comment: @AmpedWeb
: web based is irrelevant: try Enterprise Architect from Sparx system

Comment: @AmpedWeb One question, why? Really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL Workbench to do this. There are many web-based apps as well. http://wb.mysql.com/

Comment: definitely use mySQL workbench.  I looked at many and it was the best, is free and can forward and reverse engineer.  Runs on Mac/Linux/Win. Outputs images. love it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/) web-based designer

Answer (score 0):

Just had occasion to use this earlier today: http://www.dbvis.com/

- Java/uses JDBC drivers so widely compatible
- Produces reasonably pretty relationship diagrams
- The free version is still pretty capable, and the cost is eminently reasonable

EDIT: Ah, not web-based, but...somethings you really can't fit into that box very well.